Is there a general interpretation for standardized beta strentgh?
After running a linear regression model I get the beta as effect size. This linear regression model was run in r using the geeglm function, specifying family= "gaussian". The model includes group status (3 levels) as predictor, a outcome, and an exchangeable correlation structure to account for the familiarity in the dataset (siblings).
For example: geeglm(educational_level ~ group_status, family = "gaussian", id = ID, data = data, corstr = "exchangeable")
By standardizing my outcome variables and running the same analysis I assume to get the standardized beta instead of the beta as output.
With the standardized beta I want to comment on the strength of my associations. I understand that the higher the standardized beta value, the stronger the association. However, is there a standard/general way to interpret the standardized beta strength? Just as the rule of thumbs in interpreting a r-coefficient (Pearson correlation coefficient) or Cohen's D.

Welcome Noa to the site. Can you be more explicit on what statistical software are you using? What function call is "GEE, 'gaussian'"? By 'r-coefficient' you mean a Pearson correlation coefficient?

A more specific answer requires also for you to share your model specification, to know whether you are dealing with interactions or higher order terms.

@Kuku I edited your suggestions!

It seems to me that "educational level" should probably be ordinal. Is it appropriate to model this as a standardized gaussian outcome?

The easy answer
First, note there are differences among software on whether they standardize only the response or also the predictor for the reporting of standardized regression coefficients, so it is better to always be explicit. If you have only standardized the outcome, then your 'beta' corresponds to the standardized mean difference for a one unit increase in the predictor (assuming you have a linear model with no interactions). Cohen's $d$ is an estimator for standardized mean differences between groups, so that would be the short answer—you could use the same thresholds.
However...
In general, rules-of-thumb cannot tell you whether an effect is relevant or large. It all depends on the context—large relative to what? Relevant for what? Often you might want to compare or benchmark the magnitude relative to other well-studied effects in the literature.
However, beware that standardizing (as in using Pearson's correlation as well) makes it so that your effect size depends on random quantities unrelated to the actual causal mechanism of the effect. Two studies could have the same covariance between predictor and outcome but still report very different 'effects' just depending on how much variability of the response there was in their sample. This has been discussed in (Greenland et al., 1986 and 1991) (and often ignored afterwards) and is why comparing standardized coefficients across studies or populations is not guaranteed without further assumptions.

References
Greenland, S., Schlesselman, J. J., & Criqui, M. H. (1986). The fallacy of employing standardized regression coefficients and correlations as measures of effect. American journal of epidemiology, 123(2), 203-208.
Greenland, S., Maclure, M., Schlesselman, J. J., Poole, C., & Morgenstern, H. (1991). Standardized regression coefficients: a further critique and review of some alternatives. Epidemiology, 2(5), 387-392.

+1, but one should note that even Cohen warned against using the thresholds he suggested. Using rules of thumb for interpreting effect sizes is a very common question on this website, e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/23775/164936
